# How to grab data from the online database?

Tags: java, android

By any chance, is there anyone who can help me? As currently I am doing my major project, and also a beginner in android and java. I am doing the login function for my project.  I took 
[reference](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) from here. However, one problem that I am facing now is I do not know how to grab the details (name and email column) from the database and display out these two information. Is there any guide on how to grab the information and display it out after the user have log in? Thank you very much.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Android uses Java. Look up examples for JDBC or any Java/database code examples. It's all the same.

Comment: are you using local sqlite database

Comment: hmm I think so. see the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Try using `SQLite` DataBase, which ships with Android.

**2.** Its simply a `file` with **NO** DATABASE SERVER.

**3.** This DB can be as **small in size** as 250KB.

**For a quick and easy example see here:**

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html

**For understanding the queries look here:**

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sqlite/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html